# How to install TP-LINK TL-WN951N Driver to Windows 7 & 8.1

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, drivers, wireless-adapter

How to install TP-LINK TL-WN951N Driver to Windows 7 & 8.1? The default driver is unstable

Comment: @pimp Default Atheros driver, a bunch of TP LINK drivers, a bunch of Atheros and HP drivers. Win7 and 8 tagged before those are target OSs

Answer (score 0):

The default driver, that gets automatically installed (the one by ATHEROS) is unstable. The adapter occasionally hangs for ~10 seconds.

Below is the walkthrough I came up with,

1. Do not use the drivers by Atheros. Instead, browse to the [TP-LINK device page](https://www.tp-link.com/au/support/download/tl-wn951n/#Driver). Click on the "Drivers" button
2. Download & extract the latest driver. As per 2020, the latest driver is `TL-WN951N_V3_130529`, from 2013-06-20.

The setup application doesn't work properly. And even worse, the alleged "Windows 8" driver missing some files for it to be installed correctly, and seemingly is a generic driver (doesn't describe itself). So instead of the standard installation process, install the driver manually (both Windows 7 and 8).

3. Go to My Computer -> Properties -> Device Manager -> (select the networking device) -> Driver -> Update Driver -> Browse my computer for driver software (Locate and install the driver manually) -> Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer -> Have Disk. Then browse to the Windows 7 driver with the same "bitness" as your OS. For example,

   - `C:\TL-WN951_V3_130529\Driver Files\Windows 7 32bit` (for 32-bit Windows)
   - `C:\TL-WN951_V3_130529\Driver Files\Windows 7 64bit` (for 64-bit Windows)
4. The driver installation wizard will then ask you whether to install 150Mbps or a 300Mbps driver. Install a 300Mbps driver ([reference](http://en.techinfodepot.shoutwiki.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN951N_v1)).

The installation process may take several minutes. It is unknown why it takes so long. But once complete, you finally have the fully and properly working Wifi adapter!